# How to redirect from inertia post call to laravel back to inertia with new data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

i have laravel+vue+inertia situation;
in my VUE component i'm having Form that sends post request to Laravel backend:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
  <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

also:

```
function submit() {
  Inertia.post("/api/myMethodInController")
}
```

in Laravel controller i fetch some data which i want to send back to page where request came from. My controller function ends with:

```
return Inertia::render('ComponentWhereRequestIsSentFrom', ['data'=>$myData]);
```

ok. I'm now getting Laravel data in my VUE component (via props), but my URL stays at POST target:

```
mydomain.com/api/myMethodInController
```

what can i do to redirect to initial URL, but with new data?

tnx a lot!

Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:** Set a redirect back with `myVariable` data in the controller.

```php
return redirect()->back()->with([
    'myVariable' => 'foo',
])
```

**2:** Define it in [HandleInertiaRequests middleware](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data).

```php
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'flash' => [
            'myVariable' => fn () => $request->session()->get('myVariable'),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

**3:** Get it in the component.

```html
<template>
{{ $page.props.flash.myVariable }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

const myVariable = usePage().props.value.flash.myVariable
</script>
```