# Inertia: receive data from backend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I need to display response from backend to frontend. I wrote this code

```
post(route('update', data), {
    onSuccess: (data) =>  console.log(data)
})
```

And into controller I wrote

```
    return Redirect::back()->with([
        'data' => 'Something you want to pass to front-end',
    ]);
```

But like can you can see I use `Redirect::back()` and into console it it display me not `data` but other data from the view. If i tryed return json, I had an error:

> All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a
> plain JSON response was received
> I don't want to use axios becouse it will be generate further problems. For example - in this way I can wrote in controller's method `return Redirect::back()` and it works but if I use axios it doesn't. So, how can I receive data from backend?

Comment: This should be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899619/14569750