# Inertia JS Flash message not printing on vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have two flash message save in "HandleInertiaRequest.php" as follow:

public function share(Request $request)
{

```
return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
    'ziggy' => function () use ($request) {
        return array_merge((new Ziggy)->toArray(), [
            'location' => $request->url(),
            
        ]);
    },
    'flash' => [
        'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('success'),
        'error' => fn () => $request->session()->get('error'),
        
    ],
  ]);
```

}

Now when a user is successfully added, I use the success message and if I get an error, I use the error message. The thing is, the success message is working fine, but the error message is not printing. Although I have checked by inspecting vue, I'm getting the page/flash/error message successfully. Can you please guide me where I'm making mistakes?

**Here is the controller code:**

```
public function station(Request $request) { $count = DB::table('stations')->where('ChildID', '=', $request->ChildID)- >get(); if (count($count) > 0) { return back()->with([ 'error' => 'Station Record Already Exisits in this station' ]); } else { //Perform db Inert and return back return back()->with([ 'success' => 'Station Record Added' ]); }
```

**Here is the vue code:**

```
 <div v-if="$page.props.flash.error" class="alert_error">
        {{ $page.props.flash.error }}
    </div>
    
    <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
        {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
    </div>
```

Comment: I think that inertia usually returns errors under `page.props.errors` instead of session flash.

Comment: This must be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899619/14569750