# Laravel Getting Data From Redirect

Tags: laravel

I have this route web.php

```
Route::get('/two-steps', [UserController::class, 'getTwoSteps']);
```

And I have these two functions :

```
public function getTwoSteps($email) {
    return view('auth.two-steps', ['email' => $email]);
}

public function someFunction() {
    return redirect('/two-steps')->with('email',$email_1);
}
```

my question is, how to pass `$email_1` into `getTwoSteps($email)` function?

thank you

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899619/14569750

Comment: Glad to read that. If so, a +1 is appreciated :P