# change prop based on parameter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In my app (Laravel + InertiaJS + Vue3), I want to refresh some client-side JS variables based on a client-side parameter:

1. Client has a table of `events`, each one holding a button with its corresponding `event_id`.
2. When pressed, the server receives a request and performs some calculations (dynamically generates an external URL and some parameters). Nothing is persisted to the database.
3. Hopefully, the generated URL and the parameters are sent-back to the client, and the user is then redirected there (client-side) using a **POST form** (that is why I can not redirect directly from the server).

What is the best way to do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
// In my controller
...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->generator = new URLGenerator();
}

public function generate(Event $event)
{ 
    $url = $this->generator->getURL($event);
    return redirect()->back();
}

 // My controller
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Events', [
        'events' => fn () => new EventResource(
            auth()->user()->events
        )
    ]);
}
```

I need to somehow inject the `$url` variable back to Vue.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This should be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899619/14569750

Comment: Yes, I have it done with flash messages as per docs, but in this case the `$url` variable could be the first of a long list of variables to pass back to Vue, along all my controllers and pages. That's why I was searching for an alternative way of doing this without having to edit the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware each time I face this situation...

Comment: Maybe you can pass in an array instead of a string, and in the front-end check if the array has n length or if has the key you search (in case it was an associative array). This way you can pass in multiple variables in the `HandleInertiaRequests` at once, and you can forget about to set the name of the variable in the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware every time you want to pass in a different variable